# Array dinâmico em php para pg_insert()

Tags: php, array

Desenvolvi o seguinte código como exemplo:

```
$dados  = "nome-luiz-idade-21-status-true";`

$arraydados = explode("-", $dados);`
```

Preciso criar um array dinâmico, onde: As posições pares de `$arraydados` sejam os nomes de cada posição em uma nova array, e as posições ímpares de `$arraydados` sejam o respectivo valor dessa posição.

Farei isso em formato de um `for`, com base no `count` de `$arraydados`.

Tentei fazer isso da seguinte maneira mas não deu certo:

```
$cntindice=0;

$cntval=1;

$arrayinsert[$arraydados[$cntindice]] = $arraydados[$cntval];
```

Alguém sabe onde estou errando?

Observação: irei utilizar essa array em um `pg_insert()`.

Comment: Porque não criar um objeto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o método que inicialmente você estava tentando, também é possível obter o resultado esperado.

Entretanto, não dá muito certo utilizar o `for` por conta de que como a *array*, no exemplo, possuirá 6 itens, o `for` tentará executar o mesmo processo 6 vezes. Então, fazendo assim:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arraydados); $i++) {
    $arrayinsert[$arraydados[$cntindice]] = $arraydados[$cntvalor];
    $cntindice += 2;
    $cntvalor += 2;
}
```

Irá ocorrer de `$cntindice` e `$cntvalor` obterem os valores: `0 (valor inicial), 2, 4, 6, 8, 10` e `1 (valor inicial), 3, 5, 7, 9, 11`, respectivamente. Mas, como a *array* só tem 6 itens, as últimas posições válidas serão 4 para `$cntindice` e 5 para `$cntvalor`, sendo que daí em diante retornará *null* (ou *vazio*).

E portanto, a partir da posição 6, tanto a chave como o valor serão *null* (ou *vazio*), e a partir daí ela ficará sendo substituída até terminar a iteração do loop.

Portanto, para que isso não aconteça, ao invés do `for`, você pode usar um `while`, dessa forma:

```
$dados = "name-luiz-idade-21-status-true";

$arraydados = explode("-", $dados);
$arrayinsert = array();

$posicaoChave = 0;
$posicaoValor = 1;

while ($posicaoChave < count($arraydados) && $posicaoValor < count($arraydados)) {
     $chave = $arraydados[$posicaoChave];
     $valor = $arraydados[$posicaoValor];

     $arrayinsert[$chave] = $valor;

     $posicaoChave += 2;
     $posicaoValor += 2;
}

//print_r($arrayinsert);
```

Ou seja, enquanto `$posicaoChave` e `$posicaoValor` forem menores que o tamanho da *array*, executa o bloco de código. Dessa forma, quando `$posicaoChave` se tornar 6 e `$posicaoValor` se tornar 7, a condição do loop não será satisfeita, assim, não executará o bloco, e consequentemente não gerará uma posição desnecessária/inválida na *array*.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: obrigado! exatamente o que eu queria ;)

Answer (score 0):

Podes antes criar um objeto JSON e converter para array com `json_decode()`

```
$dados  = '{"nome":luiz,"idade":21,"status":true}';

$arr = json_decode($dados, true);  //o parametro true vai converter em array associativa

print $arr->{'nome'}; // luiz
```